# Getting an integer from console input

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get an integer from user input. I used the following

```
int locationX = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
myObject.testFunction(locationX);
```

and got an unexpected error related to my testFunction. I used the debugger and found that when I input the number 2 into console - locationX becomes 50. What is going on here and how can I get locationX to match the user input?

Comment: What is `myObject.testFuction`?

Comment: Its just a dummy function, the variable locationX is 50 before its called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the input typed by the user when he/she presses the enter key.
This is done using `Console.ReadLine`. But you have a problem in the following `Convert.ToInt32`.
If the user doesn't type something that could be converted to an integer your code will crash.

The correct method to read an integer from the console is

```
int intValue;
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if(Int32.TryParse(input, out intValue))
    Console.WriteLine("Correct number typed");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The input is not a valid integer");
```

The [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will try to convert the input string to a valid integer. If the conversion is possible then it will set the integer passed via out parameter and returns true. Otherwise, the integer passed will be set to the default value for integers (zero) and the method returns false.

TryParse doesn't throw an expensive exception like `Convert.ToInt32` or the simple `Int.Parse` methods

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads the next character from the console input stream, not the entire line, which explains why you're getting a weird result.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()` -

```
int locationX = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't read the console input until the user hits ENTER.

```
int locationX = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
myObject.testFunction(locationX);
```